# Why does compiling this .dtx produce a blank page at the beginning?

Tags: package-writing, docstrip

This is my first time using `docstrip`. I've written the `attempt.dtx` file shown below. However, if I compile `attempt.dtx` using

```
pdflatex attempt.dtx
```

the generated documentation starts by a blank page (immediately followed by the title page). My TeX distro (TeX Live 2013) is up to date. I've compared my `dtx` to others on CTAN to identify what I'm doing wrong, but I seem to be doing everything right...

Where is that blank page coming from and how can I get rid of it?

### attempt.dtx

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%
% Copyright blah blah blah
%
% \fi
%
% \iffalse
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2011/06/27]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{attempt}
%<package>  [2014/02/21 v0.1 test test test]
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{attempt}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{attempt.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \CheckSum{0}
%
% ￼\GetFileInfo{attempt.sty}
%
% \title{attempt}
% \author{Jubobs}
% \date{\filedate}
% \maketitle
%
% \begin{abstract}
%   test test test
% \end{abstract}
%
% \section{Introduction}
%
% \StopEventually{\PrintIndex}
%
% \section{Implementation}
%
% \Finale
\endinput
```

Comment: You have three spurious characters before `\GetFileInfo`

Comment: Yes! I should have guessed: I copied and pasted most lines from a PDF ([Scott Pakin's *How to Package Your LaTeX Package*](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dtxtut)). You're a life saver!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I paste the line

```
% ￼\GetFileInfo{attempt.sty}
```

in the http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/ input box, I get, in the Unicode U+hex box

```
% U+FFFC\GetFileInfo{attempt.sty}
```

So it's a spurious character that produces the problem. It appears as three bytes if Unicode is disabled; here's what `less` shows:

```
% <EF><BF><BC>\GetFileInfo{attempt.sty}
```

In the .log file you find

```
 (./attempt.dtx
Missing character: There is no <EF> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <BF> in font cmr10!
Missing character: There is no <BC> in font cmr10!
 [1
```

that's also a way to find the culprit.